# Post Request to web server with Flask

Tags: python, post, web, flask

When you run this python script, you will see a feature of network connection with flask on 127.0.0.1:5000/

But, I could not figure out to print all of features of network from starting to run script. I mean I'm losing the previous data, so I could print any one feature of my network to my web server when refreshing my page.

I haven't found anything specific in Flask documentation. Some say urllib2 or post.request is useful for it, but I'm new to Flask and Python for web at all.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
import socket, sys
from struct import *
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():  

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

while True:

        packet = s.recvfrom(65536)

        packet = packet[0]

        ip_header = packet[0:20]

        iph = unpack('!2B3H2BH4s4s' , ip_header)    

        t_length = iph[2] 
        protocol = iph[6]

        s_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[8]);
        d_addr = socket.inet_ntoa(iph[9]);

        protocol_s = protocol    

        if protocol == 1:
            protocol_s = 'ICMP'
        if protocol == 6:
            protocol_s = 'TCP'
        if protocol == 17:
            protocol_s = 'UDP'

        tcp_header = packet[20:40]

        tcph = unpack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_header)

        dest_port = tcph[1]     

    test = 'Protocol : ' + protocol_s + ' | Source Address : ' + str(s_addr) + ' | Destination Address : ' + str(d_addr) + ' | Dest Port : ' + str(dest_port) + ' | Packet Length : ' + str(t_length)

    return test

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Please fix your code identation.

Comment: What are `features of network`? What are you actually trying to find?

Comment: Protocol, source and destination address, destination port, packet length..

Comment: Flask is not a server; it is a WSGI application. But WSGI applications are designed to **work with HTTP**, which is a *TCP-only* protocol. The WSGI application **doesn't have access to the individual packets**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Flask is a WSGI framework. It will only work on TCP/IP and HTTP is the protocol you will use in *most cases*. You might use websockets and other protocols, but they will also work over TCP. The socket handling is already done by the server and you do not have to worry about it.

For getting information about the connection, I'm not sure how much you can get out. You can take a look at the [`flask.Request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#incoming-request-data) and the [`werkzeug.wrappers.Request`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.Request) objects.

For example, you can get the remote address from the `request`:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    print request.remote_addr
```